# Ways to run cron jobs dynamically on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron

I want to run **Rails CRON jobs** dynamically on **Heroku**.

Times should be stored in a **database**.

So CRON jobs should run dynamically on times from the **database**.

I want to run on Heroku so **whenever** gem won't work for me.

Is there any way to run CRON jobs dynamically on **Heroku**?

Comment: I think you are looking for "heroku scheduler"

Comment: @Vishal it is not possible to run CRON jobs dynamically by code using Heroku scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I have done dynamic job scheduling on Heroku, Here is what I've done:

1. I scheduled a Job(Job-A) which will be run every hour.
2. `Job-A` will fetch the all `survey_launch` which are scheduled in the next hour.
3. `survey_launch` time is to be set dynamically by the user, I've used `DateTime` format.
4. So, every hour `job-A` will fetch the next hour's launches and scheduled a cronjob.
5. this process will be executed every hour so that if any user updates any survey launch time then this dynamic scheduler will work accordingly.

Note: I needed to consider the time zone as well when scheduling the jobs.

Hope you can also schedule the jobs dynamically like this for your app.

Answer (score 0):

I have run cron jobs dynamically using **[sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq)** and **[sidekiq-cron](https://github.com/ondrejbartas/sidekiq-cron)** gems.
First, I have added worker.

```
class HardWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  def perform(name, count)
    # do something
  end
end
```

Second, I have added Schedule worker which updates cron job times when times in the database are changed.

```
hour = Schedule.last.hour # get **hour** from database
min = Schedule.last.min  # get **min** from database
schedules = [
  {
     'name': 'Hard Worker'
     'class': 'HardWorker'
     'cron': "#{min} #{hour} * * *"
  }
]

Sidekiq::Cron::Job.load_from_array schedules
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). It needs no special setup to run on Heroku.

Install gem and initialize db and define your cron tasks in initializers/arask.rb:

```
arask.create task: 'send:logs', cron: '0 2 * * *' # At 02:00 every day
arask.create task: 'my:awesome_task', interval: :hourly
arask.create script: 'Attachment.process_new', interval: 5.hours
```